# Using an array as expression for applying ngClass

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am trying to apply a class if a value matches any of the elements of an array. My approach is like below-

```
sectionHeaders:Array<string>=["Appearance", "Personality and Interests", "Relationships", "In The Anime", "Anime", "Name", "Character Songs", "Trivia"];

<ion-item *ngFor="let info of characterInfo.sections">
    <h2 class="heading" [ngClass]='{"redBackground" : info?.title == sectionHeaders}'></h2>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can't work. Your title is not equal to the array of section headers. You want to apply the class if the title is **contained** in the section headers. `indexOf()` allows knowing that:

```
[ngClass]="{redBackground : sectionHeaders.indexOf(info?.title) >= 0}"
```

Arrays are a basic building block of any JavaScript application. You should take some time to study the methods they have: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array